# How do I change the GDM Theme in 19.10?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, gdm, icon-themes

This question has been asked before, but for an old version f ubuntu, I tried those solutions, and they did not seem to work.

Is there any way to change the GDM theme, icon theme, and cursor theme?

Comment: you need to install all those themes after downloading. there are command line ways and GUI. for GUI install `gnome-tweaks` and `gnome-shell-extensions` package. for GDM theme CLI is the best way.

Comment: @PRATAP Interesting. I have gnome-tweaks and my desktop changed and working fine, and I just tried to change the css files manually for GDM login, but it didn't work out too well. Any ideas?

Comment: what are the changes are you trying? can you explain with a sketch highlighting which elements?